# SAP HANA uses which Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, hana

**My Main Question is which Eclipse IDE is used for SAP HANA development?**

I am trying to build an application using SAP HANA, and a guide tells me to get an Eclipse IDE from [the download site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads). However, I have found that there are a lot of version/type of Eclipse IDE, such that Eclipse for C/C++, for Java, for PHP, etc.

Which one should I choose to download and install?

Answer (score 4):

You can download the basic eclipse installation.
Others installations have plugin pre-installed, but you can install them anytime you want through the update-site system.

You can download SAP dev tools plugins for eclipse  on [this adress](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/) 
You choose the luna or kepler software site and add them in eclipse under :

```
Help > Install New Software > Add... : type in the url selected
```

Comment: I will try to download and do it. Will post here later after i tried out. Thanks for the answer! Much appreciated.